# Ruby snippet for reading lines block

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am new to ruby and seeking help.
We got the csv files having the column with data shown below. Using the csv parser and fetch the column data for each in a variable.

And we want to change column data from csv file to line shown below and write to a file:

FROM

```
---
- - status
  - New
  - Delivered
```

TO

`status from New to Delivered`

Thanks @igian for help

```
---
- - status
  - New
  - Delivered
- - Milestone
  - Sprint1
  - Sprint
```

I was struggling for this. I tried to use y.second but it fails, please correct what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to show your code.  If this is yaml, then you should add that as a tag and mention that fact in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a YAML file, see https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.2/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html

Load the file then handle the array:

```
require 'yaml'

y = YAML.load_file( 'the_file.yaml' )
y #=> [["status", "New", "Delivered"]]

words = y.first
p "#{words[0]} from #{words[1]} to #{words[2]}"
#=> "status from New to Delivered"
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. As data is stored in a variable, I used `YAML.load(var)`.